# С#: XML и WinForms

Tags: c#, windows, .net, xml, winforms

Есть некоторый XML, который хотелось бы связать с компонентами на форме и выполнять манипуляции.
Например:

Редактируя TextBox редактируется соответствующий узел в XML.

Добавляя элемент, добавляется узел и т п.

На ум приходит только десериализация. Можно ли еще как-нибудь решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону `XDocument` или `XmlDocument`. Они обеспечат удобную загрузку, выгрузку, хранение и взаимодействие с XML. А дальше уже на вкус и цвет, какая задача так и используйте. Выбор конкретного класса из предложенных - аналогично, исходя из задачи с учетом предлагаемой функциональности.